# PHP MySql query 2 tables that have no common attributes at the same time?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to query 2 tables in a database, each query having nothing to do with each other, other then being on the same page.

Query 1 - The first query on the page will retrieve text and images that are found throughout the page from Table A.

Query 2 - The second query will retrieve several products with a image, description and title for each product from Table B.

I know that putting the second query inside the first query's while loop would work but of course is very inefficient.

How can I and what is the best way to retrieve all the data I need through 1 query?

Thanks,

- Dane

Comment: Why combine them if they are not related?  And why would you execute query 2 inside of the loop for query 1 if they are not related?

Comment: ircmaxell - isn't having 2 query's on the same page inefficient?

Comment: I'd rather have 2 simple queries than 1 overly complex query.  Both from a maintainability standpoint and a performance standpoint.  Less is not always better...

Comment: @teamdane Stick with the 2 query approach until you've profiled your application and found it to be a bottleneck. It's common for web applications to issue many queries per page load.

Comment: @ircmaxell: but two will include an overhead of data transfer between application server and db server,.

Comment: @ovais.tariq: The only "overhead" will be one TCP round trip.  There will be no data overhead, since you're still transmitting the same data anyway in both directions (considering that the 2 queries are about the same size as the single combined)...  And if you're THAT TCP bound where the one extra round trip is slowing things down significantly, I suggest you find another host...

Comment: @ircmaxell: the data is gonna be transmitted two times,. first when php sends the first query to the mysql server and fetches the result, then when the second query is run and results fetched,. 
btw i had mentioned this fact cz it should be kept in mind,. may be it doesnt make any difference know but in some other scenario it can,.,

Comment: But no extra data is transmitted.  The larger query is going to be >= the sum of the two smaller queries.  And the result of the larger query will be the union of the two smaller ones.  So the only difference will be one query which is double the size (both in send and receive) vs two small queries.  But the total data transferred will be for the most part identical (excluding the minor protocol overhead).  Don't believe me?  Wireshark it.  You'll see that the total data transferred in both cases is practically identical...  And that's not counting the efficiency of a simple query...

Answer (score 3):

So all you want to know is if its ok to have 2 queries on the same webpage? Its A-OK. Go right ahead. Its completelly normal.  No one expects a join between table news and table products. Its normal to usetwo queries to fetch data from two unrelated tables.

Comment: They are not related, so it's ok to have 2 querys on the same page?

Answer (score 0):

Use LEFT or INNER JOIN (depends on whether you want to display records from TableA that have no correspondent records in TableB)

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM TableA a
[LEFT or INNER] JOIN TableB b ON (b.a_id = a.id)
```

Comment: I need all records from Table A and all records from Table B. There is no id to join them on, no columns are related.

Comment: In this case I'd have 2 independent queries.

Answer (score 0):

If there's no way to relate the two tables to each other, then you can't use a JOIN to grab records from both. You *COULD* use a UNION query, but that presumes that you can match up fields from each table, as a UNION requires you to select the same number/type of fields from each table.

```
SELECT 'pageinfo' AS sourcetable, page.id, page.images, page.this, page.that
WHERE page.id = $id

UNION

SELECT 'product' AS sourcetable, products.id, products.image, product.other, product.stuff
```

But this is highly ugly. You're still forcing the DB server to do two queries in the background plus the extra work of combining them into a single result set, and then you have to do extra work to dis-entangle in your code to boot.

It's MUCH easier, conceptually and maintenance-wise, to do two seperate queries instead.